# Desentendimento em scopo da função

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma estrutura para começar a desenvolver em node, sou iniciante então me perdoem qualquer coisa.

indexModel.js

```
var Model = require('./model.js');

var model = new Model();
var data;

class IndexModel {
    // Função inicial
    constructor() {
    }
    // Data banco
    banco() {
        return model.Query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ?', [2], 'select');
    }
    // Retorne a data;
    data() {
      return data;
    }
}
```

model.js:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var data;

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "nodejs",
  timezone: "-3:00"
});

class ModelModel {
    // Função inicial
    constructor() {
        con.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Connected!");
        });
    }
    // Retorna o valor da query passada
    Query(query, array, type) {
        con.query(query, array, function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
          switch (type) {
            case 'select':
                data = results;
                break;
            case 'insert':
                data = results.insertId;
                break;
            case 'update':
                data = 'changed ' + results.changedRows + ' rows';
                break;
            case 'delete':
                data = 'deleted ' + results.affectedRows + ' rows';
                break;
            default:
                data = results;
                break;
          }
        });
        return data;
    }
    ReturnQuer(result) {
        data = result;
        console.log('aqui'+data);
    }
}
```

Preciso receber o valor de data fora da função, porem sempre recebo 'undefined', dentro da função estou recebendo tudo corretamente, gostaria de saber se existe forma de receber o return do resultado da query, ou se estou fazendo algo errado.

OBS: Retirei o 'use strict' e module.exports pois por algum motivo não consigo adiciona-lo na ferramenta de texto do stackoverflow como um código.

Comment: Informe o código completo do seu módulo. Só com esse pedaço fica difícil identificar o erro.

Comment: Pronto, adicionei as demais partes (:

Comment: Leonardo, o teu problema é que `.Query` dá uma resposta assíncrona. Dá uma olhada a essas outras pergunta/reposta que indiquei em cima. Resolvem o mesmo tipo de problema.

Comment: Entendo, mas não me atende estas soluções, gostaria de algo que esperasse o retorno do mesmo, mas infelizmente parece que não existe esta solução no momento.